# ISABOUT deprecated for CONTAINSTABLE?

Tags: sql-server

I recently used ISABOUT in a search function (at work, for searching names), I submitted a code review, and the senior engineer indicated that ISABOUT is deprecated. He gave me the link below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/search/-search-sql-isabout

The article above was written on 05/30/2018. I have come across some posts here on stackoverflow regarding the same topic, but the posts are almost 8 years old. There is nothing online that suggests that ISABOUT is deprecated for CONTAINSTABLE. I wanted to know if ISABOUT is deprecated for CONTAINSTABLE, and if so, what should I use in its place?

Comment: The article concerns [Windows Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/search/-search-sql-ovwofsearchquery). You tagged the question with `SQL Server`. Which one is it?

Comment: My code was written for a .Net Application, the function which returns the results of the search on the .Net Application resides on a SQL Server.

Comment: That is still vague enough, but in case you are in fact talking about TSQL code executed by the SQL Server database engine, you should not be concerned with Windows Search. The [`ISABOUT` predicate in SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/containstable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) is not marked as deprecated.

Comment: Apologies for being vague, thanks for answering the question.